Print and Print Preview of Web Page not Working Properly in Microsoft Edge Browser
I have a strange issue I am experiencing with a web app. Typically, the user right clicks on the web page and click Print. He views the document in preview and then decides how to print it.
On Chrome, everything works fine
On Microsoft Edge, It only works if you right click the web page at the top of the page. If you scroll down to the bottom of the page before you right click and select print, the printed document is not formatted properly. The print preview is also not formatted properly. See screen shots below:
On Chrome - (User right click from bottom of page)
You can see the title of the app, title of the report, report run date etc

On MS Edge - (User right click from bottom of page)
The preview starts at some random data as shown below. Title of the app, title of report etc are not shown in the preview and printed version.

As you can see from the above screen shots, Chrome is displayed properly. MS Edge only displays like that if I right click on the web page from the top of the page without scrolling down
Below is my code sample:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Physician Activity Report</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
</head>

Below is the content of mycss.css
@media print {
    .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6,
    .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
        float: left;
    }

    .col-md-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .col-md-11 {
        width: 91.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-md-10 {
        width: 83.33333333333334%;
    }

    .col-md-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }

    .col-md-8 {
        width: 66.66666666666666%;
    }

    .col-md-7 {
        width: 58.333333333333336%;
    }

    .col-md-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .col-md-5 {
        width: 41.66666666666667%;
    }

    .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33333333333333%;
    }

    .col-md-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .col-md-2 {
        width: 16.666666666666664%;
    }

    .col-md-1 {
        width: 8.333333333333332%;
    }
}

h5 {
    color: darkblue;
}

What can I do to get this to work properly on MS Edge ? Is it a CSS issue ?

I'm not seeing what the problem is. The formatting appears to be the same in both screenshots.

Hi @TimR, the Chrome version has the title of the application, title of the report as shown in the screen shot while the MS Edge version starts from the content as shown

Perhaps Edge is showing the current page that was right-clicked on? Without interacting with it ourselves, we can only make guesses. Both show it would print 19 pages. Is it still wrong when all pages are printed? How about printing from the top menu or Ctrl+P (or applicable platform hotkey combo)?

Yeah it is still wrong when all pages are printed @TimR

Hi @TimR, Ctrl+P works if I do it while I am at the top of the web page. If I scroll down to the button of the web page, then I experience same issue. Basically, the printing works if you are at the top of the web page. As soon as you scroll down it doesn't work. On all other browsers I don't experience the issue. The problem now is majority of users use MS Edge so I need to fix this

It's a known issue in Edge version 126. The fix has been included in Stable 126.0.2592.81, which had been released on June 27, 2024. Please install the latest Edge Stable version 126.0.2592.81 (Official build) and test again.

Hi @Yu Zhou, it works. Thank you
